# Perl: regular expression: capturing group

Tags: regex, perl

In a code file, I want to remove any (one or more) consecutive white lines (lines that may include only zero or more spaces/tabs and then a newline) that go between a code text and the concluding `}` of a block. This concluding `}` may have spaces for indentation before it, so I want to keep them.

Here is what I try to do:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\s+\n([ ]*)\}/\n($1)\}/g' file
```

For example, if my code file looks like (□ is the space character):

```
□□□□while (true) {\n
□□□□□□□□print("Yay!");□□□□□□\n
□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□\n
□□□□}\n
```

Then I want it to become:

```
□□□□while (true) {\n
□□□□□□□□print("Yay!");\n
□□□□}\n
```

However it does not do the change I expected. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Regex probably isn't the right tool for this.  When your IDE cleans up formatting this way, it using a parser (and might be compiling along the way as well).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get these cases sometimes because I run my files through a script that removes all comments. So I would like to clean it up with the same script.

Comment: Is your code perl? Then I'd suggest getting perltidy and using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -0777 -e's/^\s*\n(?=\s*})//mg' yourfile
```

(Remove whitespace from the beginning of a line through a newline that precedes a line with } as the first non-whitespace.)

Answer (score 1):

The only issues I can see with your regex are

- you don't need the parenthesis around the matching variable,
  and
- the use of a character class when extracting the match is
  redundant (unless you want to match tabs as well as spaces).

So, you could try

```
s/\s+\n( *)\}/\n$1\}/g
```

instead.

This works as expected when run on your test input.

To tidy it up even more, you could try the following.

```
s/\s+(\n *\})/$1/g
```

If there might be tabs as well as spaces, you can use a character class. (You do not need to include '|' inside the character class).

```
s/\s+(\n[ \t]*\})/$1/g
```

Comment: Thank you for they idea to expand the group. I just figured out that when I use `$1` I am not supposed to warp it with parentheses. :) Also I haven't noticed that in my case the indentation was done by tabs, so combined with your version I changed it to `s/\s+(\n[ |\t]*\})/$1/g`

Comment: @rapt: Hi. You don't need the alternation metacharacter | inside the character class. So perhaps `s/\s+(\n[ \t]*\})/$1/g` will suffice. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex instead, which uses a positive look-ahead assertion. This way you only capture the part that you want to remove, and then replace it with nothing:

```
s/\s+(?=\n[ ]*\})//g
```

Comment: Almost there - I think you have to move the `\n` into the look ahead, otherwise it will be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following one liner

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\s*\n*(\s*\n)/$1/g' test
```

Comment: Almost there - but it removes also other white lines that are not right above a `}`.